# Refresh a variable passed from django view to javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I pass a variable from the views.py file to multiple javascript template and want to refresh that variable every time I click on certain parts of the window. Loading the variable from views to the template is simple enough, but I don't know how to pass that variable back to the views then send it back to update the templates.

Comment: AJAX might help you. there are many packges for to implement ajax.
one of them is(which i prefer) https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do that via Ajax. It's the only way you would be able to execute a server-side view and hand back data, most likely JSON, that could be used to update a JavaScript variable.

If you're looking for a way to automatically update the DOM when changes in client-side data occur, I highly recommend [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: Well I guess it's finally time to pick up AJAX. I started doing web development recently and I'm slowly picking up the necessary skills. Thank you!

Comment: Ajax isn't as difficult as it might seem. I would recommend getting familiar with Firebug if you're not already. My other advice would be to not use jQuery as if it were a framework :)